# Error Calling Stored Procedure from C#/ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server

The following stored procedure **pr_generate_sales_order** generates records in 2 tables SO Header & SO Detail for database DB1. Then it exports SO Header & Detail records From DB1 to DB2.

Whenever I try to call this SP from ASP.Net/ C# it generates the following error message:
**A cursor with the name 'c_customers' does not exist** and no record will be created in the Database.

However, if i execute this stored procedure **pr_generate_sales_order** directy in SSMS then it works fine and it generates records in DB1 & DB2.

Where's the problem ? is it related to Begin Try Catch ... ???

```
USE [DB1]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Name: pr_generate_sales_order
-- ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Parameters: 
--    - N/A
--
-- Description: 
--    Generate Sales Order in DB1 & DB2
-- ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
alter procedure [dbo].[pr_generate_sales_order] () as

Begin

-- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Variable declaration
-- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Declare @v_error_number             nvarchar(10)
Declare @v_error_message_en         nvarchar(1000)

Declare @v_customer_id              int
Declare @v_time_log_id              int
Declare @v_hourly_rate              numeric(18, 5)
Declare @v_total_time               numeric(18, 5)
Declare @v_description              nvarchar(max)

Declare @tmp_time_log Table
(
    time_log_id                     int,
    customer_id                     int,
    sku_id                          int,
    hourly_rate                     numeric(18, 5),
    hours                           int,
    minutes                         int
)


-- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Main program
-- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Set @v_error_number = '0'
Set @v_error_message_en = ''


Begin Try

    Begin Transaction T1


    -- ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    -- 
    -- ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Insert Into @tmp_time_log
    Select      tl.time_log_id                          as time_log_id
                , tl.customer_id                        as customer_id
                , tl.sku_id                             as sku_id       -- 24/09/2013
                , tl.hourly_rate                        as hourly_rate
                , tl.hours_rounded                      as hours_rounded
                , tl.minutes_rounded                    as minutes_rounded

    From        time_log tl

    Where       tl.transaction_date between '2013-01-06' and getdate() 



    -- ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    -- Open Cursor
    -- ------------------------------------------------------------------------

    -- ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    -- Declare Customer Cursor: Get the list of Customer
    -- ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Declare c_customers cursor for 
    Select      distinct IsNull(customer_id, 0)
    From        @tmp_time_log

    Open c_customers

    Fetch Next From c_customers Into @v_customer_id

    While @@fetch_status = 0
    Begin

        -- ----------------------------------------------------------------
        -- Create Sales Order Header for each Customer
        -- ----------------------------------------------------------------
        Insert Into sales_order_header ...

        -- Get Sales Order Header Id
        Set @v_sales_order_header_id = scope_identity()


        -- ----------------------------------------------------------------
        -- Declare Time Log Cursor: Get the list of Time Log by customer in order to Create 
        -- ----------------------------------------------------------------
        Declare c_time_log cursor for 
        Select      time_log_id                     as time_log_id
                    , hourly_rate                   as hourly_rate
                    , cast( (cast(tl.hours as numeric(18, 5)) + (cast(tl.minutes as numeric(18, 5)) / 60) ) as numeric(18, 5))       
                                                    as total_time
                    , sku_id                        as sku_id
        From        @tmp_time_log tl
        Where       customer_id = @v_customer_id

        -- ----------------------------------------------------------------
        -- Open Cursor
        -- ----------------------------------------------------------------
        Open c_time_log

        Fetch Next From c_time_log 
        Into @v_time_log_id, @v_hourly_rate, @v_total_time, @v_sku_id

        While @@fetch_status = 0
        Begin

            -- Create Sales Order Detail for Each SO Header
            Insert Into sales_order_detail ....


            -- Get the next Cursor
            Fetch Next From c_time_log Into @v_time_log_id, @v_hourly_rate, @v_total_time, @v_sku_id
        End


        -- Close & Deallocate Cursor
        Close c_time_log
        Deallocate c_time_log


        -- Get the next Cursor
        Fetch Next From c_customers  Into @v_customer_id
    End

    -- Close & Deallocate Cursor
    Close c_customers
    Deallocate c_customers


    -- ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    -- Export Sales Order Header & Detail From DB1 to DB2
    -- ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Exec [DB2].[dbo].[pr_import_sales_order_from_db1]


    --  
    Commit Transaction T1

End Try

Begin Catch
    -- If Error Found Then Rollback Transaction
    If @@TRANCOUNT > 0
    Begin
        -- Close & Deallocate Cursor
        Close c_customers
        Deallocate c_customers


        -- Rollback         
        Rollback Transaction T1
    End

    -- Get Error # & Error Message  
    Select  @v_error_number = ERROR_NUMBER()
            , @v_error_message_en = 'An error occurred in ' + ERROR_PROCEDURE() + ': ' + ERROR_MESSAGE()

    GOTO Step_END

End Catch

-- ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Return: Error # & Error message
-- ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
STEP_END:
    Select  @v_error_number                 as error_number  
            , @v_error_message_en           as error_message_en

End
GO
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you get an error at

```
exec [DB2].[dbo].[pr_import_sales_order_from_db1]**  //are those asterisks there in your code
```

Then you've already closed & deallocated c_customers, but your going call those close & deallocate calls a second time in your catch block, which I assume is the problem.

**Edited after last comment**

Paul,

You should reorganise the last 4 lines of your Try block as follows.

**ORIGINAL**

```
Close c_customers
Deallocate c_customers

Exec [DB2].[dbo].[pr_import_sales_order_from_db1]

Commit Transaction T1
```

**MODIFIED**

```
Exec [DB2].[dbo].[pr_import_sales_order_from_db1]

Close c_customers
Deallocate c_customers

Commit Transaction T1
```

The reason for doing this is as it currently stands, if you `CLOSE` & `DEALLOCATE`  the cursors, and then an error occurs in your DB2 SPROC, you'll try to `CLOSE` & `DEALLOCATE`  the cursors a second time in your catch block.

In the modified/rearranged version, if everything works fine, you'll still close & deallocate the cursor prior to your `COMMIT TRAN`, but if that DB2 SPROC pukes, it'll jump straight to the catch block and the `CLOSE` & `DEALLOCATE` in the catch block will work as expected.

Comment: Just to add to this, the OP will want to check the user account his connection string is using to see if it actually has access to DB2 (and that proc).  I suspect the reason `pr_import_sales_order_from_db1` is failing is due to a permissions problem.

Comment: @ChrisLively: You are right! Initially i was Calling SP in C# using a user for DB1. So now, i try it using the user SA and it works fine and it creates records in DB1 & DB2!!! In addition I kept close & Deqallocate cursor in the rollback section ... Thank you Chris

Comment: @Paul:  Glad that helped.  Although I'm not sure what you mean by keeping close and deallocate in the rollback section.  Your code needs to be changed around so that no matter what the cursor is closed and deallocated exactly one time.  No more, no less.

Comment: @ChrisLively: We should always close a cursor ... I must use this way because in case an Exception has been thrown while cursor is looping it's gonna tell us that the cursor is still open ... So that's why I CLOSE it and DEALLOCATE it ... I had this situation in the past!!